# the behavior of IntelliJ Idea Vim is something strange

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I use Ctrl+k for exiting Insert mode. 
So, I did the key mapping on IntelliJ.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQfJK.png)

it seems work well. But, something is wrong.

When I type Ctrl+k, it looks exited insert mode.
but after the input ctrl+k, next input is not recognize.

it's difficult to explain for my poor English. so please try setting Ctrl+k as a Exit Insert Mode, and check the behavior.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure alternative shortcuts for the Vim emulation keys as Vim key mappings as in the original Vim. See the Vim help for `:map` commands. You can put those mapping into your ~/.ideavimrc.

A small example:

```
inoremap <C-K> <Esc>
```

Configuring them via "File | Settings | Keymap" is not supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is the first time for me to find solution at stackoverflow